# Проблемы с code blocks на macos

Tags: c++

Скачал code blocks на macos big sur, начинаю писать код и вылезает прямоугольник серого цвета.Непонятно, что за баг.
Закрываю приложение, снова открываю, создаю новый проект и снова эта же проблема, он закрывает текст.
Что делать?спасибо.

Comment: очень похоже, что это срабатывает автодополнение кода. Почему оно такое - это другой вопрос

Comment: @KoVadim, а как его отключить?